# run Kafka Broker on Databricks

Tags: apache-kafka, databricks

I would like to install a Kafka Broker on Databricks directly.
The purpose is only to demo a local kafka use case using Spark Streaming.

Here is how I proceeded :

```
wget https://packages.confluent.io/archive/7.4/confluent-7.4.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf confluent-7.4.0.tar.gz 
./confluent-7.4.0/bin/zookeeper-server-start ./etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties&
./confluent-7.4.0/bin/kafka-server-start ./etc/kafka/server.properties&
```

That last command however throw a bizarre error :

```
./confluent-7.4.0/bin/kafka-server-start ./etc/kafka/server.properties&

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/databricks/jars/----ws_3_3--mvn--hadoop3--org.apache.logging.log4j--log4j-slf4j-impl--org.apache.logging.log4j__log4j-slf4j-impl__2.18.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/databricks/driver/confluent-7.4.0/share/java/kafka/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[2023-07-06 12:48:45,041] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2023-07-06 12:48:45,629] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:42) ~[kafka_2.13-7.4.0-ce.jar:?]
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:91) ~[kafka_2.13-7.4.0-ce.jar:?]
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) ~[kafka_2.13-7.4.0-ce.jar:?]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Option.orNull(Lscala/$less$colon$less;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at kafka.utils.Exit$.exit(Exit.scala:28)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:127)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)`
```

Any idea what could trigger this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OneCricketeer's answer led me to double check Scala / Kafka version compatibility

[Indeed](https://index.scala-lang.org/apache/kafka) : *"Scala 2.12 support has been deprecated since Apache Kafka 3.0 and will be removed in Apache Kafka 4.0"*

And Databricks in [NOT](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/when-will-databricks-runtime-be-released-for-scala-2-13/m-p/7174) supporting Scala 2.13 (*yet*)

So I stuck to Kafka 2.2.2 as it is the last to support 2.12 by default

https://index.scala-lang.org/apache/kafka/artifacts/kafka

[image: kafka versions]

I dont need confluent at all, but [just in case](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html) :

I used the 5.2 version to get the 2.2 kafka, and got it to work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying you're using an incorrect Scala version for the broker

Try downloading a 2.12 version, if available. You also don't need Confluent Platform

Comment: databricks uses 2.12 as a default, but kafka's latest version support 2.13. So I had to downgrade kafka to 2.2.2. the error phrasing was not that "obvious".Thanks for the hint.